# Slow Performance while concurrent uploading to S3 using console

Tags: performance, amazon-s3, concurrency, console

I'm trying to make a simulation through using s3 console to upload many files at same time to same bucket.(using an EC2 client in same account, and same region of S3 bucket)

Opening 3 browser sessions on the console, for each session about 300 files to be uploaded, and once ready, press the upload button for the 3 sessions at same time, what happens next is that about 75% of files in all 3 consoles get uploaded in normal/fast speed (almost 2 minutes), then a kind of throttling begins in all 3 consoles and remaining files takes an hour to be uploaded.

Anyone can advice?

Comment: The AWS console is certainly not designed for performance testing.  Use one of the many APIs available for S3.

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar, also further investigations imply using CLI will lead more consistent performance, I'll try it first

Comment: CLI worked as a charm